# Question about insulating / winterizing outside faucet

Tags: plumbing, insulation, winterizing

It's that time of year to insulate the faucets. I had a question about the R value of using a faucet cover like the Frost King ones versus wrapping the faucet with a towel. What is more effective?

[image]

I have been using a arduous process of wrapping my faucets

1. I tightly wrap the faucet with a towel
2. then shrink wrap around the towel
3. Then put a old grocery bag to around that to keep water out
4. then wrap that with shrink wrap to hold everything in place

[image]

Comment: Personally I would use frost proof valves but that requires some plumbing skills. You have an interesting solution but I cannot answer because I do not know the environment you are in. If North Dakota, that would be different than Florida. I am in Michigan and all of my outside faucets, sprinklers etc are on a separate plumbing loop. When I winterize the sprinklers (blow out with compressed air) it only takes a moment to do the other valves.

Comment: I can only guess you figured out that is what you need to do. Living in Arizona I have no clue if that is too much or not. I do know they make valves that are frost proof. Google it.

Comment: You need to include your location. None of those will work in Minnesota, but in Key West probably anything will

Answer (score 3):

Simplest and I would argue best is to turn off an inside valve for the winter, and open the outside valve long enough to drain water out of it before closing it again. Nothing to freeze, mo freeze damage.

Answer (score 0):

The question is what method is more effective?
Answer is if both cause the faucet not to freeze, then both are equally effective.
Which is more efficient?
The frost King method takes less time, so it is more time efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You asked about the R-value.

It depends on material and Thickness.

Frost King with foam housing at 1 inch thick can provide a R-value of 3.

Can not tell you if that is enough since it is based on your freezing temperature.

The thicker the better.

Your towel + plastic has much lover R-value

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be answered without knowing the heat loss through the brick wall (which supplies the heat to prevent frosting), the worst case outside temp, the wind, and the R value of your solution.

If you are inclined to rig your own solution and perform some quality assurance, you could put a wireless thermometer probe in the faucet and confirm the temperature throughout the coldest nights.

Otherwise you have to go with empirical evidence, such as what your neighbours use and what the shops in your area sell. This is probably the most reliable and effective approach.

Towels are generally not great insulators since they are made of cotton. Plus, any humidity captured over time, for instance from the wall and despite all the wrapping, will ruin the R value.